# Rewrite url to hide query string and convert .php to path

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is my actual `.htaccess` filw:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . //index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This in my root. Now I have an index file redirecting to the inder of /production.

So my website is here: `www.mywebsite.com/production/index.php`

In production folder I have another `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?nav=$1 [QSA]
```

But something is wrong. Actually, if I go to `www.mywebsite.com/production`, it shows my index. But if I navigate another page, example `www.mywebsite.com/production/contacts`, it does not load `contacts.php` but `index.php` again.

About the query strings, I think the `.htaccess` file inside the production folder, rewrites query strings from index only, while not working for, example, `contacts.php?nav=something`. What's wrong? It's so confusing...I've been trying for hours.

Comment: I suspect that because of that second commented `RewriteRule` your two first `RewriteCond`s are also taken into account for that last `RewriteRule`. That of course means it will never get applied...

Comment: And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: of course i'm using .htaccess because i don't have direct access to http server. Anyway i commented that rules since it was applying to the root index only and not going deep in subfolders.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to comment something. What I was trying to point out is that you _only_ commented that rule, but not the conditions before that rule. So the conditions are still evaluated and what rule are they applied to? Not the commented one, obviously, but the one below. That leaves you with three conditions for the last rule with the first two being exactly the opposite of each other. That means the last rule (the only one not commented) will _never_ get applied.

Comment: I commented rewrite conditions too, but it's all working the same as before. And it still is a problem since every path redirects to homepage instead of its page name.

Comment: That should be an endless loop... Your redirection rule inside the production folder will rewrite: `/production/contacts` => `/production/index.php?nav=production` => `/production/index.php?nav=index.php&nav=production` => ...

Comment: Ah, no, actually it will be `/production/contacts` ?> `/production/contacts.php` which most likely will result in a 404...

Comment: do u have a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no, I do not currently understand what is actually happening on your side... But maybe I have some hint: to debug rewriting issues the best thing is to sit down and examine closely what is going on inside your http servers rewriting engine. Best tool for that is rewrite logging. It allows you to follow each tiny step inside the rewriting engine one by one. Usually that sheds some light.

Comment: what is happening is either i type mywebsite.com/production/index or mywebsite.com/production/contacts, it always load index.php, while with the second link it should load contacts.php

Comment: ` contacts.php`  is rewritten to `index.php` by your rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` style file in the protuction` folder.

Comment: right, that is. How do tell the style to rewrite every page containing a query string as a path? example index.php?nav=homepage -> index/homepage, contacts.php?nav=contacts -> contacts/contacts. Or just hide the query string so it remains index/ and contacts/ .

Comment: Such thing certainly _is_ possible, however this sounds like a very strange thing to do. I'd suggest instead to take a closer look at what rewriting strategy you actually want or need. Something like `contacts.php?nav=contacts` sounds architecturally broken to me...

Comment: you are perfectly right, it's weird :D this is happening because i'm calling in each page the header separately. And in header, i have a menu that switches its class to "active" based on which page is loaded. This value is passed via query string (?nav=) .

Comment: Why does a header sent another request to the server for that?

Comment: i have header.php . It's included in both index.php and contacts.php . If i call "?nav=home" from index.php, it "lights" the menu for Home button. If called "?nav=contacts" from contacts.php, it "lights" the menu for Contacts button. That is.

Comment: You don't need an extra request for that! You can either do that by means of client side logic (the loaded page knows its URL...) or, if you really want to do that on the server side, by checking the referrer.

Comment: i know, but i want that "?nav=contacts" gets replaced by "/contacts/". So the url would be "mywebsite.com/production/contacts/contacts". It's ugly but i will think about it later, at the moment i want this behaviour. How do I achieve it?

Comment: If you want to invest into such thing, sure, go ahead... I suggest you start reading the documentation, since you apparently have not done so... It is of excellent quality and comes with good and easy examples. You have to start reading it anyway. Start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html